# Render function of datatables add extra text

Tags: javascript, server, datatable, datatables

I have used the following for rendering the datatables column.

```
{
    sortable: false,
    "render": function (data, type, full, meta)
    {
        var testId = full.TestId;
        var bodyId = full.BodyRegion;    
        var link = '<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline grey-salsa" onclick="OnLoadIndividualHTMLReport("+testId",bodyId);">&nbsp;Report</a> ';    
        return link;
    }
}
```

But, after rendering the column, I got some extra text

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline grey-salsa" onclick="OnLoadIndividualHTMLReport(" +testid",bodyid);"="">&nbsp;Report</a>
```

[image]
"="

How can I remove the extra text?

Answer (score 0):

You don't Just have an extra `"="`, your generated html has the `testid` and `bodyid` variables in it, when you really want your generated html to have the values of those variables, not references.  You are missing a plus sign `+` after `testId` in the concatenation of your `link` variable, and that concatenation should be using the single quote since that is the delimiter you are using on the outside, the double quotes are inside the string constant that becomes your html, then you want to do the same for `bodyId`.  Corrected line of code:

`var link = '<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline grey-salsa" onclick="OnLoadIndividualHTMLReport(' + testId + ', ' + bodyId + ');">&nbsp;Report</a>';`

Comment: If this answer helped, please be sure to [mark it as such](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)